# DiscordJS edit existing embed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I want to edit a existing embed in discord.js. But Im getting the error that `message.edit` is not a function.

Code:

```
        await mongo().then(async mongoose => {

        const results = await applicationSchema.findOneAndDelete({
            guildId: guildId,
            applicationId: applicationId
        })

        for (const application of results.applications) {
            const { applicationId, userId, appliedfor } = application
            user22 = bot.users.cache.get(userId);
            let acceptembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(colours.maincolour)
                .setDescription(`Lieber <@${userId}>! Deine Bewerbung wurde angenommen!`)
            user22.send(acceptembed)
                // m = reaction.messages.cache.fetch(applicationId);
                // m.edit(null, { embed: output });
            let message = bot.channels.cache.get('823554343827013652').messages.fetch(applicationId)
            await message.edit()
        }

    })
```

Comment: You need to await here: `let message = await bot.channels.cache.get(...).messages.fetch()` as fetch returns a promise.

Comment: Alright. Thank you @ZsoltMeszaros its working now c:

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are sending should be put in `.edit()` as it would for `.send()`. Please note that this does not add to the message, but instead replaces it.

```
bot.channels.cache.get('823554343827013652').messages.fetch(applicationId)
    .then(message => message.edit(acceptembed));
```